# How can I detect if user selected from createChooser options?

Tags: android

I have a code that will prompt user to send a message by selecting the desired application, how can I detect if the user actually have chose from the options or instead pressed Back?

I tried to check if the intent returned something, but is running asyncronous so cannot be tracked.

Also I have tried to run the intent with `startActivityForResult`, what I noticed in onActivityResult that resultCode is always 0(`RESULT_CANCELED`) even if user selected, or not from the chooser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Android's source, you can see that the Activity that chooses among Intents doesn't setResult() at all. That should be requested as a feature.

Comment: Is there anyway to know which application they had selected?

Answer (score 0):

you can now use the new createChooser() with 3rd arg: pendingintent.getintentsender().

example:

```
        String aText = e.getText().toString();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, aText);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

        //
        Intent receiver = new Intent(this, BroadcastTest.class);
        receiver.putExtra("test", "test");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send email with:", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```